# How to set wget to timeout after downloading more than a fixed duration

Tags: wget, timeout

I want wget to (attempt to) start downloading, then if isn't done after 10 seconds, I want it to give up.

```
wget --timeout 10 http://url
```

Seems like a reasonable try, but it seems like it only sets --dns-timeout, --connect-timeout, and --read-timeout. Thus, it could wait 9 seconds for dns, another 9 for connect and then keep downloading forever, as long as data keeps coming at a steady pace (no 10+ second pause).

Answer (score 1):

Basically this will be something like:

```
wget http://www.somesite.com/file.zip &
PID=$!
sleep 10
if [ `ps ax | grep $PID` -ne '' ]
   then
   kill $PID
fi
```

Comment: That's one way to solve it, ugly as it is.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't *exactly* what you're asking as this should only cause Wget to timeout if the download idles for more than 10 seconds:

```
wget --read-timeout= 10 http://url
```

About the `--read-timeout` option, from the [Wget 1.13.4 Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Download-Options):

> Set the read (and write) timeout to seconds seconds. The “time” of this timeout refers to idle time: if, at any point in the download, no data is received for more than the specified number of seconds, reading fails and the download is restarted. This option does not directly affect the duration of the entire download.